# iPhone Settings app and keyboard control?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, settings

So I'm putting my app's preference settings into the Settings app.  One of the settings is an edit text field (PSTextFieldSpecifier).  When touched, the keyboard dutifully appears, I can make the edits, but when I press Return....nothing.  Well, the editing is completed, but the keyboard remains.  I see no way to make the keyboard go away.

I also notice this same behavior in other Settings panes, including those from Apple.  Do I assume correctly that this is just standard behavior and I need to just accept the fact that my Settings table has now been reduced to half size, and just deal?

Furthermore, I gather there is no approved way to have a "rich" child pane display, such as that seen in Settings->General->About->Legal?  Or a way to do what appears to be a -presentModalViewController, a la Settings->General->Passcode Lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to deal with it. And there's nothing you can do in code, at least for now.

That's a bug that hasn't been fixed for a while. You should fill out a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to a call to resignFirstResponder ... e.g.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)tf
{
    [tf resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: He isn't running code; he's using the system designed way to present settings in the setting app.